# ASP.NET web.config authorization - Allow access to root but not child folders/pages

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-config

I want the login page to be the root of my site www.mysite.com/ (default route) and then have all other folders/pages below that require the user to be logged in.

Is there any easier way than using the following as the global rule and then specifying a deny rule for each child under a location element:

```
<authorization>
  <allow users="?"/>
</authorization>

<location path="/SubFolder1"> <!-- repeat for each child -->
   <system.web>
      <authorization>
         <deny users="?"/>
      </authorization>
   </sysetm.web>
</location>
```

Comment: yes..make a authorize filter..

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your master page

```
 protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckAuthentication();
    }

    //Check if the user is authenticated 
    private void CheckAuthentication()
    {
        if (!Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
        }
    }
```